# CSS circles without width or height? : Is this possible with pure CSS or not?

Tags: jquery, css, geometry, css-shapes

I can turn a div into a circle like this:

```
.circle {
 background-color: rgba(0, 0139, 0139, 0.5);
 height: 200px;
 width: 200px;
 -moz-border-radius:50%;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 border-radius:50%;
}

<div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

But i have to specify width height:

I want to display three rows of text in DIV's with "no-wrap" so each of the 3 segments of text have there own line and are not wrapped.

I want to display these in the center of a circle and have the circle expand to fit the lines of text.

The text lines will be pulled from a database via PHP, and will vary in character length.

The problem is the method shown above only works if the width / height is specified.

Is this possible with CSS using only, using percentages or would i need a JS work around.

thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think it is possible. However, you could try setting width and height to auto and then set your <p> tag, or what ever tag you use for the text to display:block; This might work, although I have my doubts.

Comment: I imagine you could work around the problem by using two divs, one positioned on top of the other.

Comment: A circle is perfectly round. If you're looking to create ovals this will be very easy. If you're growing circles, keep in mind that the width and height will grow exponentially to maintain perfect circle status.

Comment: Thanks everyone, @Kris gave your idea a go but with no luck

Comment: @mblase75 how would i implement it to give the 1:1 ratio required like MetalFrog mentioned.

Comment: I am open to a jQuery solution if anyone has an idea of how i could implement that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Pure CSS Solution with some caveats

[This fiddle demonstrates a solution using only css](http://jsfiddle.net/y4Ede/90/). It works flawlessly (I think) in modern browsers (IE9+, which is needed for `border-radius` anyway) ***with single lines of text***. Caveats are:

1. As you can see by the pink "circle" the text must all be contained in a single element (not multiple spans as in the pink). That is not a big problem.
2. To get any kind of "padding" one needs to put a transparent `border` on the `span` set to the "padding" size. This should also not normally be a big issue, since it is unlikely you would want borders inside the circle.
3. As you can see by the css on the cyan circle, ***if multiple lines of text are expected*** (or forced in my case by a `max-width`), then css for `margin-top` and `top` properties must be set according to the number of text lines. This could be an issue depending on application. On the stacked version, IE9 needed `overflow: auto` set to get it to size correctly.
4. As you can see by the red circle if you narrow the display area, if `white-space: nowrap` is not set and a circle begins wrapping its single line of text, then some ovular distortion of the circle occurs.

Each web designer would have to determine if the limitations of this solution can be accounted for or not. If not, then the javascript solution posted here by rgthree should work well. But if only a single line (or some set number of lines, like in my cyan circle) are expected, then this css solution should work well.

Comment: Nice one, thanks everyone. Hopefully someone else will find this usefull too!

Comment: Wow great answer, i tweaked it a little for smaller circles like the ones used as badges - see here: http://jsfiddle.net/zcd75Lcd/

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is replace you height and width with a padding and display inline-block. Reference: http://jsfiddle.net/6mzP7/

```
.circle {
   background-color: rgba(0, 0139, 0139, 0.5);
   padding: 200px;
   display: inline-block;
   -moz-border-radius:50%;
   -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
   border-radius:50%; 
}

​<div class="circle"></div>
```

The HTML can stay the same.

Comment: try adding some divs or spans inside that circle div, with varying amounts of content, and you'll see that it doesn't maintain the circle shape

Comment: Didn't see need for content the first time i read it. Sorry about that. Not sure then. May have to do it with JQ.

Comment: It does seem to work but only if the padding is twice the with of the content or more.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that you can achieve what you want simply with CSS.  I took a crack at a scripted solution to the problem...

The CSS:

```
.circle {
 background-color: rgba(0, 0139, 0139, 0.5);
 -moz-border-radius:50%;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 border-radius:50%;
 padding:10px;
}
.circle span {
white-space: nowrap;
}
.circle div {
position:relative;
top:0;
left:0;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="circle">
    <div>
        <span>this is some text</span>
        <span>this is some more text</span>
        <span>this is text</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The script:

```
$(function() {
    var widest = 0;
    $('.circle span').each(function(){
        thisWidth = $(this).innerWidth()
        if (thisWidth > widest) {
            widest = thisWidth;
            };
    });
    $('.circle').css('width',widest).css('height',widest);
    $('.circle div').css('top',(widest - $('.circle div').innerHeight())/2);
});
```

Edit: I've created a fiddle of this suggestion: http://jsfiddle.net/4m2ZZ/

Comment: Not having any luck with this, any chance of sticking it up on jsfiddle.net ?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I mistook your question. You'll need Javascript to assign the hight width to the highest value, as well as make sure your content is centered.

Here's how in this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rgthree/K4Kpw/

```
<div class="circle">
    <div>
        <span>This is a line</span>
        <span>This is yet another line!</span>
        <span>Last Line!</span>
    </div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
.circle {
    position:relative;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0139, 0139, 0.5);
    padding:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius:50%;
}
.circle > div{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$('.circle > div').each(function(){
    var h, w, max;
    w = $(this).width();
    h = $(this).height();
    max = w > h ? w : h;
    $(this).css('margin-left', -parseInt(w/2,10));
    $(this).css('margin-top', -parseInt(h/2,10));
    $(this).parent().width(max);
    $(this).parent().height(max);
});​
```

Comment: Looks rather like an oval instead of a circle to me.

Comment: Touche, it is. I incorrectly took "circle" to mean "circular." I'll remove.

Comment: Updated to use Javascript, as there's no CSS way (I know of) to force a width to match the height, or vice-versa.

Comment: Brilliant thats got it nailed. Thanks @redlena your method works too... Shame it seems there's no way of doing it pure CSS.

Comment: @user1308628--there is a pure CSS solution assuming the constraints of your goal meets certain criteria. See my answer for the solution and caveats that limit its use to certain applications.