# Creating a perfectly symmetrical circle using border-radius without specifying a height or width

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

It appears setting my `border-radius` to either `50%` or `100%` didn't do the trick and gives the span tag a stretched appearance. Is it possible to get this circle perfectly symmetrical without setting a height or width to it?

```css
span {
  background: #232323;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 6px;
}
```

```html
<span>x</span>
```

Comment: How about a bullet `content: '\x02022'; font-family: sans-serif;` (if I'm correct) and control with `font-size`?

Comment: I claim no credit for this but have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k5doehae/). I found this code on the internet a few months back and had stored the crux of its content for future analysis (which I never managed to to :P).

Comment: Is the content of span always one letter? If so, this will work for any font-size http://jsfiddle.net/pts4cemx/5/

Comment: @Harry I understand you weren't the sole creator but definitely worth posting as an answer. At this point in time Google really doesn't crawl fiddles that well.

Comment: Funnily enough Google does return the source and [here it is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981274/css-circles-without-width-or-height-is-this-possible-with-pure-css-or-not) :)

Comment: @Harry Thanks for your help in finding this.

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to just set the `width` to the computed font height:

```
width: 1em;
```

```css
span {
  background: #232323;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px;
  width: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<span>x</span>
```

Comment: That's still not a perfect circle.

Comment: I can see what @BoltClock is talking about. The sides seem squished.

Comment: Yes, this needs tuning of the padding using the font-size unit. I must leave now, I'll remove my answer if it isn't easily fixable.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```css
span {
    background: #232323;
    border-radius: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 1.35em;
    padding-bottom:.2em;
}

span.medium {
  
  font-size: 50px;
}


span.ridikulus {
  
  font-size: 500px;
}
```

```html
<span >x</span>
<span class="medium">x</span>
<span class="ridikulus">x</span>
```

Comment: What did you have to determine mathematically to get this to work? I see that something was done with both `width` and `padding-bottom` using `em` as your unit of measure.

Comment: No math :p I just messed with it for a few seconds to get what looks like a circle then tried different sizes to see if it stays the same

Answer (score 0):

To provide an alternative approach, instead of relying on `border-radius`, I was thinking about using a glyph `&bull;` and position that on the span tag.

The size can be adjusted using `font-size`.
The big advantage is that you don't need to generate a perfect circle.

```css
span {
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 1;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
}
span:before {
    content:'\02022';
    color: #000;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 10rem;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    line-height: 0;
    left: -14px;
    top: 20px;
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
```

```html
<span>x</span>
```